# how to give text editor to dropdown combo in MVC3 and how to fill the combo box list depending on entered value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, combobox

I'm using MVC3 for my web site. and I want to give **text editor to the dropdown combobox** and depending on typing text(when user **keypress that time data should be loaded depending on the whole text from text editor of drop down combo box**) i want to fill the combo box. Is it possible? how to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried? What specific difficulties did you encounter? What is your question?

Comment: Simple: You need *to give text editor to dropdown combo and fill the combobox depending on entered value*

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I've done this in asp.net project with the help of ajax AutoCompleteExtender control with text box. I've not done anything in MVC3.

Comment: @Mohayemin: Can you suggest useful document related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [jquery-ui Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)